# Change GCM API KEY for Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Presently, I have a scenario where my company had previously out sourced the Android app. Now, they have in house developers developing the app.

The GCM credentials like sender id and API key are available with the old company to whom the project was out sourced previously. We don't have access to it as it was registered on previous company's personal gmail id.

What I want to do is to be able to create a new API key on my own gmail account with the same package name and use it in the app.

Is this possible?? Or I am stuck with this?

How will this affect new users?

EDIT

Would I need to maintain two API keys? One for the users with old API keys and one for users with new API keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those API Keys only grant access to services. They don't discriminate users for different API Keys.

Those `API Keys` and `sender_id` can be located on the code, on the gradle files or the `google-services.json` files on the `app` folder.

Said this and answering you last question, the old users **wont notice the change of API Key token**, but for example, if you're using the GCM service, all the old devices should update their `RegId` with the new `SenderId` and `API Key`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes it does help. Thank you.